# Meaningless output of Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The output of the command

```
Limit[D[(Exp[x]-1-x)/x^2,{x, n}],x ->0,Direction-> "FromAbove",Assumptions -> n > 2 &&
 n \[Element] Integers]
```

> `((DirectedInfinity[(-1)^n] + DirectedInfinity[(-1)^(1 + n)]) n!)/Gamma[2 + n]`

is meaningless in view of

```
((DirectedInfinity[(-1)^n] + DirectedInfinity[(-1)^(1 + n)]) n!)/  Gamma[2 + n] /. n -> 3
```

> `Indeterminate`

and

```
Limit[((DirectedInfinity[(-1)^n] + 
  DirectedInfinity[(-1)^(1 + n)]) n!)/Gamma[2 + n], n -> 3]
```

which returns the input.

It is clearly understood that the result of

```
FullSimplify[FindSequenceFunction[Table[Limit[D[(Exp[x] - 1 - x)/x^2, {x, n}], x -> 0, 
Direction -> "FromAbove"], {n, 3, 6}], n] /. n -> n - 2]
```

> `1/(2 + 3 n + n^2)`

is only a guess, not a workaround. We still have no certainty about the values of the limit under consideration for
astronomic values of `n` (BTW, `FindSequenceFunction[{-3, 5, -7, 9, -11}, n]` returns the input.).

Is there a relaible workaround for this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of the $n$th derivative of a function at zero is equal to $n!$ times the $n$th coefficient in the functions Maclaurin series:

```
limit[n_] := n! SeriesCoefficient[(Exp[x] - 1 - x)/x^2, {x, 0, n}]
Simplify[limit[n], Assumptions -> n >= 2 && n \[Element] Integers]

(* n!/(2 + n)! *)
```

Why Mathematica doesn't simplify this further to `1/((n+1)(n+2))` I can't say, but it's definitely a more useful form than what `Limit` yields.

Comment: +1. A clever move. However, I hesitate to accept your answer since  "


The limit of the $n$th derivative of a function at zero is equal to $n!$ times the $n$th coefficient in the functions Maclaurin series" is made by hand.

Comment: @user64494:  Fair enough;  perhaps someone will come up with something more automated.

Comment: I draw a decision to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Using this command

```
Assuming[n > 2 && Element[n, Integers], 
 Limit[D[(Exp[x] - 1 - x)/x^2, {x, n}] // Simplify, x -> 0] //FunctionExpand]
```

I am getting

$$\frac{1}{(n+1) (n+2)}.$$

Comment: -1. Sorry, cannot reproduce it (see [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8a2jezktofnctd/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-09-08%2019.02.49.png?dl=0)) on a fresh kernel of 12.3.1.

Comment: @user64494 I'm also on fresh kernel. Not my fault, we probably have different versions. I am `11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 27, 2017)`

Comment: @user64494 But as a side note, your downvote is not fare in this situation. The criticism is directed towards a person who simply had a few minutes of free time and wanted to help. If I were you, I would not close the post so fast, but would wait for the comments of other people, to see at what version the problem emerged. Maybe its just the default options for the `Limit`.

Comment: The same result in Wolfram Cloud (see [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/loskioj3vddilf3/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-09-08%2020.11.54.png?dl=0)).